# Display items in colums with a specific order

Tags: html, css

I have some elements of different heights which I need to align on 2 columns in the the following order:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

I need the divs to 'touch each other', meaning that the bottom of #1 should touch the top of #3, no matter the size of #2.

So far I tried to to it this way:

HTML

```
<div class="block block--1">1</div>
<div class="block block--2">2</div>
<div class="block block--3">3</div>
<div class="block block--4">4</div>
<div class="block block--5">5</div>
<div class="block block--6">6</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.block:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
}
.block--1 {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
}
.block--2 {
    background: blue;
    height: 150px;
}
.block--3 {
    background: yellow;
    height: 200px;
}
.block--4 {
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
}
.block--5 {
    background: grey;
    height: 200px;
}
.block--6 {
    background: orange;
    height: 300px;
}
```

But this doesn't work as #3 doesn't touch #1. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/oynrv880/1/

I have tried using the column-count property as well but it displays the item is the wrong order.

How can I do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try using a table instead?

Comment: with a tables, items on the same row would have the same height right?

Comment: What's the problem with CSS columns? Can't you change your HTML markup at all?

Comment: The problem with CSS columns is the order. I need a row based order which is not possible using css columns

Comment: @Spearfisher: But, if you can change the HTML markup, you can change the markup to reflect that order. Odds first, followed by evens. This would be easiest for you. See here - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/1dm52e7k/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get without modifying your HTML is probably something like this:

You can make the odd ones float left and the even ones float right, and clear their respective side.

```
div {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
div:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h11q8v99/1/)

Comment: in the jsfiddle there is a gap between 4 adn 6, is there a way to move 6 up?

Comment: I think not, because 6 starts floating at the level of 5. So as long as 5 starts lower than where 4 ends, I'm pretty sure there is no solution except modifying HTML or using JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="float:left; width:50%;">
    <div class="block block--1">1</div>
    <div class="block block--3">3</div>
    <div class="block block--6">6</div>
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:50%;">
    <div class="block block--2">2</div>
    <div class="block block--4">4</div>
    <div class="block block--5">5</div>
</div>
```

Remove all CSS attibutes of .block

Answer (score 0):

Are you OK with something like this?

```css
.block {
    width: 100%;
}
.block:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
}
.block--1 {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
}
.block--2 {
    background: blue;
    height: 150px;
}
.block--3 {
    background: yellow;
    height: 200px;
}
.block--4 {
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
}
.block--5 {
    background: grey;
    height: 200px;
}
.block--6 {
    background: orange;
    height: 300px;
}

.first, .second {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="block block--1">1</div>
  <div class="block block--3">3</div>
  <div class="block block--5">5</div>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <div class="block block--2">2</div>
  <div class="block block--4">4</div>
  <div class="block block--6">6</div>
</div>
```